# how to run test database in django?

Tags: python, django

I set a test database in the `test_settings.py` file like this:

```
from myproject.settings import *

SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False

DATABASES['default'] = {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'}
```

But while running the test like below:

```
python manage.py test --settings=myproject.test_settings myapp
```

it is not accessing the specified database and not creating any tables. How can I use the specified database in testing and how can I set the foreign key checks to zero?

Comment: You need to specify `NAME` of the DB as well.

Comment: i specified the name of the db also but not working                                           DATABASES = {
    'default': {
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
         'NAME': os.path.join(_DB_DIR, 'dev.db'),
         'TEST_NAME': os.path.join(_DB_DIR, 'dev_test.db'),
    }
}